# JSR-303 errors not being resolved by spring:message tag

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

**Current issue**

I got a use case where I need to use both Spring Validator and JSR-303 validations for validating a modelAttribute. Validation works perfectly. Errors raised from my custom Spring Validator are being translated adequately. JSR-303s on the other hand works (errors are raised and part of the binding results), but the codes are not being translated. In fact, I see the code itself.

Example of the issue:
Leaving one field empty (which is covered by my custom validator down below), and another field empty (which is covered by a JSR-303 annotation).

Output is the following in the JSP:

- error.applicationContactEmailAddress.required (the JSR-303 error that did not translate properly)
- Please enter a french homepage warning title. (my custom validator error message that was translated properly)

**AppConfigController.java**

```
public class AppConfigController {

@Autowired
private Validator jsr303Validator;

@Autowired
private AppConfigValidator appConfigValidator;

@InitBinder("appConfig")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(jsr303Validator, appConfigValidator);
    binder.setDisallowedFields("id");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processUpdate(@Valid @ModelAttribute AppConfig appConfig, 
                            BindingResult result,
                            SessionStatus status) {

        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return UPDATE_VIEW;
        } else {

            ...

            status.setComplete();

            return SUCCESS_REDIRECT;
        }

    } else {
        return "common/error";
    }
}
```

}

**AppConfigValidator.java**

```
@Component
public class AppConfigValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return AppConfig.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

    AppConfig appConfig = (AppConfig) target;

    if (appConfig.isHomePageWarningEnabled()) { 
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "homePageWarningTitleFr", "error.homePageWarningTitleFr.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "homePageWarningTitleEn", "error.homePageWarningTitleEn.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "homePageWarningFr", "error.homePageWarningFr.required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "homePageWarningEn", "error.homePageWarningEn.required");
    }
}
```

}

**AppConfig.java**

```
public class AppConfig extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
    @NotEmpty(message = "error.applicationContactEmailAddress.required")
    @Email(message = "error.applicationContactEmailAddress.invalid")
    private String applicationContactEmailAddress = "";

    ...
}
```

I also got the issue with custom constraints like:

```
@Hostname(message = "error.smtpServerHostname.invalid")
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

    String[] baseNames = {
            "resources.messages.layout.LayoutResources",
            "resources.messages.layout.MenuResources",
            "resources.messages.option.AppConfigResources",
            "resources.messages.global.GlobalResources",
            "resources.messages.contact.ContactResources",
            "resources.messages.currentsession.CurrentSessionResources",
            "resources.messages.welcome.WelcomeResources",
            "resources.messages.user.UserResources",
            "resources.messages.role.RoleResources",
            "resources.messages.profile.ProfileResources"
    };

    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    messageSource.setBasenames(baseNames);

    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean jsr303Validator() {

    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(this.messageSource());

    return localValidatorFactoryBean;
}
```

**Custom JSP tag (so displaying errors in a JSP is always a one-liner)**

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="${modelAttribute}">
<section id="errors-placeholder" class="alert alert-danger">
    <h3><spring:message code="header.errors" /></h3>
    <p>
        <ul>
            <spring:bind path="${modelAttribute}.*">
                <c:forEach var="error" items="${status.errors.allErrors}">
                    <li><spring:message message="${error}"></spring:message></li>
                </c:forEach>
        </spring:bind>
        </ul>
    </p>
</section>
```

**Typical use in a JSP**

```
<t:errors modelAttribute="appConfig"></t:errors>
```

**While debugging the "result.hasErrors()" line from AppConfigController.java **

It looks like my JSR-303 errors codes (what's in the "message" attribute of JSR-303 annotation) are not getting translated/processed by Spring. Instead it is placed in the "defaultMessage" attribute.

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'appConfig' on field 'applicationContactEmailAddress': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.appConfig.applicationContactEmailAddress,NotEmpty.applicationContactEmailAddress,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [appConfig.applicationContactEmailAddress,applicationContactEmailAddress]; arguments []; default message [applicationContactEmailAddress]]; default message [error.applicationContactEmailAddress.required]
Field error in object 'appConfig' on field 'homePageWarningTitleFr': rejected value []; codes [error.homePageWarningTitleFr.required.appConfig.homePageWarningTitleFr,error.homePageWarningTitleFr.required.homePageWarningTitleFr,error.homePageWarningTitleFr.required.java.lang.String,error.homePageWarningTitleFr.required]; arguments []; default message [null]
```

Any idea how I could tell Spring to add my codes to the codes[] already added by convention ([NotEmpty.appConfig.applicationContactEmailAddress, NotEmpty.applicationContactEmailAddress, NotEmpty.java.lang.String, NotEmpty])?

Thank you

Comment: For the record, it works if I use one of the expected codes (ie: NotEmpty.appConfig.applicationContactEmailAddress). I would still like to use a custom message so I can leverage our local naming convention for i18n keys. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to surround the custom message code with curly braces like so:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{error.applicationContactEmailAddress.required}")
```

Source:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/75737-how-to-customize-jsr-303-error-messages?p=482719#post482719

Hope this helps somebody